# Вместо кириллицы метод ReadLine () принимает ноль терминаторы

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ru");
        Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Default;
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Default;
        string k = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine(k);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Default;
> Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Default;
> ```

C#, в отличие от джавы и некоторых других языков, отлично работает с юникодом в консоли. Так что удали это.